# Web2py: use language independent identifiers for translation

Tags: translation, web2py

In my native language some terms are context dependent, while in English they are translated equally in all contexts. 
So I would prefer to use context specifying identifier

`T('task.title') -> en: "Title", ru: "Название"
T('person.title') -> en: "Title", ru: "Титул"`

and then add translations for this identifiers to all used language files.

I tried it, but it looks like web2py doesn't look up string translation for default language (English in this case), so instead of 'Title' it returns 'task.title'.

Is there any way to use language-independent identifiers instead of default language phrases in Web2py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
T('Title ## task')
T('Title ## person')
```

See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Comments-and-multiple-translations.